# How to cut off the lower part of the second of two side-by-side divs?

Tags: css

I have two divs with some content (two React Tables) and they are positioned side-by side as following:

[image]

The CSS I use looks as following:

```
.table-container {
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

.left-table {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 250px;
}

.right-table {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.dictionary-hat {
    height: 75px;
}

.dictionary-hat-left {
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
}

.dictionary-hat-right {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
}

.dictionary-hat-left-text {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.dictionary-hat-right-text {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant part from your html as well

Comment: When using `display: table-cell` all cells in the same row will have the same heigth. You either position them otherwise (float/ flex) or you make an extra div inside the right cell, with the background color.

Comment: @Sirence: There is React code.

Comment: @LinkinTED: I've supposed that table-cells are equal.

Comment: Just add the rendered HTMl then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the white space marked with the red box, I recommend you use floating elements for this.

Take a look at this Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq8yd9yp/)

The contents of .left-table and .right-table can still be html tables, but you get rid of the big white space.

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="background">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left-table">
            <div class="content">
                Lorem Ipsum
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                Lorem Ipsum
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                Lorem Ipsum
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-table">
            <div class="content">
                Lorem Ipsum right
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-table {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

.right-table {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.background {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
.background:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```